# Read data from a file in a csh script

Tags: text-processing, csh

Is there a way to read data from a csv file into a Cshell script?

I have a small script, which calls another script recursively with a set of parameters. I want to read this set of parameters from a data file. How can I do this? I am having trouble implementing this using awk.

My data file is of this format:

```
ecc obliq precu
0.035765 23.778 302.46
0.034552 23.709 286.67
.
.
```

And this is my code:

```
set ecc = (0.035765 0.034552 0.033316 0.032062 0.030792 0.029511 0.028223 0.026935 0.025652 0.024384)
set obliq = (23.778 23.709 23.629 23.541 23.447 23.35 23.253 23.158 23.069 22.989)
set precu = (302.46 286.67 270.94 255.27 239.68 224.17 208.78 193.52 178.43 163.54)

@ i=1000
@ k=1

while ($i <= 1009)
    cd Run${i}
    Run${i}/run${i} $i $ecc[$k] $obliq[$k] $precu[$k] >&! xout &
    @ i= $i + 1
    @ k= $k + 1
end
```

So instead of setting the variables like in the code above, I want to read the variables ecc, obliq and precu from a data file. How can I do so? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: [Are you sure you can't use `sh`?](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) Or even call `awk` for the whole job.

Comment: This is part of a bigger script, and I have my other scripts in csh as well. So I would prefer to use csh, even though it has its own pitfalls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
set file='foo.bar'
set ecc=(`awk '{print $1}' "$file"`)
set obliq=(`awk '{print $2}' "$file"`)
set precu=(`awk '{print $3}' "$file"`)
...
```

You can substitute command output into another command like so: `` foo `bar` ``, which is the same as calling `foo` with the output of `bar` as arguments.

`awk` can be used to separate the columns: `print $1` will get the first column in the input, `print $2` the second, etc. Make sure to use single quotes, so the `$` variables do not get substituted.

Comment: +1 I was about to post the same. You can strip the header of the data file by starting output in line 1 with `awk 'NR > 1 { print $1 }' "$file"`.